What is the best way to avoid date conversion in the where clause?
What is the best way to do date and datetime filtering in the Where clause without converting or casting? This is slowing down my system and the execution plan shows 98% is used in the conversion process. My database is SQL Server.
SELECT 
    S.*
FROM
    Delivery_Records S (NOLOCK) 
LEFT JOIN   
    TBCustomers C1 (NOLOCK) ON S.CustomerAgreementCode = C1.CustomerID COLLATE Database_Default
INNER JOIN  
    TL_Customers C2 (NOLOCK) ON S.PrimaryAgreementCode = C2.CustomerID COLLATE Database_Default
LEFT JOIN   
    L_Customers C3 (NOLOCK) ON S.TransferAgreementCode = C3.CustomerID COLLATE Database_Default
WHERE   
    (S.GrowthCycle = 'a')
    AND (CONVERT(CHAR(23), S.Date, 121) BETWEEN @DateFrom AND @DateTo)
    AND (CONVERT(CHAR(23), COALESCE(S.EntryDate, '1900-01-01'), 121) >= @CreateDateFrom)
    AND (S.WarehouseCode = 't')
    AND (S.ContractHolder = '') 
    AND (S.Identity= '-0000-0000-000000000000')
    AND (S.OwnershipType = @OwnName OR @OwnName = 9)
ORDER BY 
    S.RecordID


The best way is to store dates as dates (and not as strings), then you don't need to convert them.

@JonasMetzler I get that but to change the table structure in my case will take ages due to dependencies. Also there are situations where we need to track exact times when an entry was done and there situations where time doesnt matter. So am looking for a quick workaround

It's clear that changing the DB structure causes some unpleasant effort, but mostly that's worthwile. Whenever you store dates as string, you are on high risk to run into trouble. For example, you don't know what is the month and what is the day. Then you use TRY_CONVERT to avoid exceptions. But then what to do with incorrect strings which can't be converted to a date? Overall, you will encounter lots of unexpected problems. And then you ask yourself why you haven't simply made the column a date(time) column.

Can you clarify what the types of s.Date, s.EntryDate, @DateFrom, @DateTo and @CreateDateFrom are

DateFrom DATE = '1998-01-01',
DateTo DATE = '2024-01-01',
date = '2022-12-01 15:51:54.613'
EntryDate =  '2022-12-01 15:90:54.613'

Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere

Why do you COLLATE? Are you columns in different collations too? That'll be a problem for performance as well.

Please show your table definition so that we know what s.Date and s.EntryDate really are. Furthermore, what are the types of @CreateDateFrom @DateTo and @DateFrom? And why are you converting to a CHAR(...) if you are dealing with dates or datetimes?

The best (and actually only way) to avoid type conversions is -- who would have thought of this -- using the correct types from the beginning ...

Using BETWEEN is problematic, even more so when dealing with datetime datatypes. https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common

@SeanLange: using BETWEEN is not problematic, as long as you know that start and end datetime are included in the result.

It seems that both Date and EntryDate in your table is of datetime data type. Then you don't need to convert() to remove the time component. Just >= and < instead of between
Change from
AND (CONVERT(CHAR(23), S.Date, 121) BETWEEN @DateFrom AND @DateTo)

to
AND S.Date >= @DateFrom 
AND S.Date <  DATEADD(DAY, 1, @DateTo)

And for the other condition, the COALESCE() is not necessary. When EntryDate is null, the condition will be false. So you only required to check for >= condition
change from
AND (CONVERT(CHAR(23), COALESCE(S.EntryDate, '1900-01-01'), 121) >= @CreateDateFrom)

to
AND S.EntryDate >= @CreateDateFrom


Maybe I'm misunderstanding something here, but assuming s.Date, s.EntryDate, @DateFrom, @DateTo and @CreateDateFrom are already of type DateTime, why not just remove the convert logic.
AND (S.Date BETWEEN @DateFrom AND @DateTo)
AND (COALESCE(S.EntryDate, '1900-01-01') >= @CreateDateFrom)


Yes, the other is datetime and am trying to convert to just date without time

@Immortal If you want to convert to date without time, just do CONVERT(DATE, s.Date) this is still sargable.  However, my preference is to use an inclusive/exclusive date range. e.g if I am looking for all events on 1st January 2024, regardless of time, I would do WHERE s.Date >= '20240101' AND s.Date < '20240102'. This removes any need for casting completely (even though I am not aware of any scenario where the former would not be sargable this covers me in case I am wrong).

Some good articles on the above Bad Habits to Kick: Mis-handling date / range queries and What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?
